# rake のコマンドが効きません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, rake

Git Bushを用いて環境構築を行っています。
実現したいことはモックの起動です。
その前段階でデータベースを作成したく、今回のコマンドを入力いたしました。
大変恐縮ですが、プログラミング全くのド素人の大学生でして、具体的なコードまで書いてご教授いただけると幸いです。

また、下にいくつか試してみたコマンドを書いていますが、どのコードを試しても同じエラーコードが出ています。
そもそもの設定に何か漏れがあるのでしょうか？

**完了させたいコマンド**

```
rails db:create
```

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
rake aborted!LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/vagrant/hogehoge/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so
```

**試したコード**

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create
$ rake -T
```

**環境**

- Windows10
- rbenv 2.7.1
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

以下の記事はご覧になりましたか？
同じエラーメッセージについて、解決方法が書かれています。

https://qiita.com/shota0701nemoto/items/523ba100690e90d22d24

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。スタック・オーバーフローでは、リンクが切れてしまっても Q&A の質をある程度保つために、リンク先の内容の概要や要約を回答の本文に入れることを推奨しています。もしよければ [edit] して改善してくださると、+1 投票しやすいです。